# Determine XY offset in meters between two lat/long points (EPSG:4326), and accurately recreating point locations using XY offset

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I have two tables in EPSG:4326, one for home locations and one for site locations. I need to be able to generate the XY offset in meters between the home location, and the site locations. I then need to be able to accurately regenerate the site locations, based on the XY offset from the home location. Currently when I use ST_Project to recreate a site location by using the specified XY offset from the home location. The results are slightly off in the Y direction. Generating lines using the same logic used to calculate the offset, is accurate. My environment is PostgreSQL 9.4.1 PostGIS 2.1.

The SQL script is my test data for this issue.  The home and sites test tables are the two tables stored in EPSG:4326. The sites table contains a delta_x, and delta_y field representing the X & Y offset in meters. The offset_lines view contains lines generated using similar logic as was used to calculate the offset. These lines appear accurate and terminate at the exact location as the site. The points_using_offsets view is a view of the site locations generated using the offsets from the home location and the ST_Project command. These locations are all slightly shifted in the Y direction. 
[image: Illustration of home, sites, offset lines, and output of ST_Project]

```
CREATE TABLE home
(
  gid integer,
  geog geography(Point,4326)
);

CREATE TABLE sites
(
  gid integer,
  geog geography(Point,4326), 
  delta_x float,
  delta_y float
);

insert into home (gid, geog) values (1, ST_MakePoint(-78.9570, 41.6241)::geography);

insert into sites (gid, geog) values (1,ST_MakePoint(-79.1133, 41.7690)::geography);
insert into sites (gid, geog) values (2,ST_MakePoint(-78.7726, 41.7801)::geography);
insert into sites (gid, geog) values (3,ST_MakePoint(-78.7753, 41.4041)::geography);
insert into sites (gid, geog) values (4,ST_MakePoint(-79.4226, 41.5032)::geography);

UPDATE sites AS st set delta_x = foo.delta_x, delta_y = foo.delta_y 
FROM
(
 SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN ST_X(s.geog::geometry) < ST_X(h.geog::geometry) THEN
      ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(h.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry) ),ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')*-1
    ELSE
      ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(h.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
    END AS delta_x,
  CASE 
    WHEN ST_Y(s.geog::geometry) < ST_Y(h.geog::geometry) THEN
      ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(s.geog::geometry)),ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')*-1
    ELSE
      ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(s.geog::geometry)),ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
    END AS delta_y, 
    s.gid   
FROM
  home as h, 
  sites as s) as foo
where st.gid = foo.gid;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW offset_lines AS
SELECT
   s.gid as gid,
   ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(ST_X(h.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(h.geog::geometry)),ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geog::geometry), ST_Y(s.geog::geometry))]),4326) as geom
FROM
  home as h, 
  sites as s;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW points_using_offsets AS
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN delta_x > 0 and delta_y > 0 THEN 
      ST_Project(ST_Project(h.geog, abs(s.delta_x), radians(90)),abs(s.delta_y),radians(0))
  WHEN delta_x > 0 and delta_y < 0 THEN
      ST_Project(ST_Project(h.geog, abs(s.delta_x), radians(90)),abs(s.delta_y),radians(180))
  WHEN delta_x < 0 and delta_y < 0 THEN
      ST_Project(ST_Project(h.geog, abs(s.delta_x), radians(270)),abs(s.delta_y),radians(180))
  WHEN delta_x < 0 and delta_y > 0 THEN
      ST_Project(ST_Project(h.geog, abs(s.delta_x), radians(270)),abs(s.delta_y),radians(0)) 
  END as geom,
  s.gid as gid
FROM 
home as h, 
sites as s;
```

Comment: When you say "slightly off in the Y direction", how much?

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking in cartesian and operating in geodetics. If you really want to do delta_x/delta_y, do the work in in geometry in some projected space, not geography. If you want to use geography, don't use delta_x/delta_y, use distance/direction, generated using ST_Distance(geog,geog) and ST_Azimuth(geog,geog).

(It's sometimes hard to visualize, but if you want to get to a point directly to the west of you, in geodetics, you don't set your direction "due west". If you're in the northern hemisphere, you set your direction "due west and a little north" and if you're in the south, "due west and a little south". The further away your destination point is, the more pronounced the effect is, until you get to transcontinental air routes, where you can fly over the pole to get between two locations that are at the same latitude. This is all becaue the shortest distance between two points in geodetics is a great circle, which only follows lon/lat lines if your two points happen to be exactly north/south of one another.)